# Eclipse do not prompt in Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, m2eclipse

I have just joined a project which have been built by another team. The project uses SVN as Revision System Control and Maven to build bundles. I use Eclipse Luna IDE.

When I try to add new class I get the error saying: "Source folder is not a Java project."

I thought that it is not a big problem and I created *.java file manually, but then when I was trying to write some code IDE didn't give me any hint related to code, Eclipse didn't add any imports automatically and it looks like Eclipse treats my java file as a simple text file.

I feel like I'd working with notepad not IDE. Does anyone know what do I have to add to project, change in configuration or whatever I have to do to make Eclipse working like Eclipse not just a text editor?

Best regards and thanks in advance,
Konrad

Comment: Did you enable the Maven nature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't enable the Maven nature when you imported the project. There are two ways to do this:

1. Import the project via "Import Maven Project" instead of "Existing Java Project".
2. Open the context menu for the project -> Configuration -> Convert to Maven Project

To check, look into the `.project` file (might not be visible inside of Eclipse). There must be a line

```
<nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
```

**[EDIT]** The project structure doesn't look right. You should checkout `trunk` from SVN, not `root`.

Comment: I have added following .project file: http://pastebin.com/6LjfUWSb but unfortunatelly it still seems not to work correctly... Maybe do I have to add some .classpath file?

Comment: Running `Update Project...` from the Maven context menu should fix the .classpath. Afterwards, all the source folders should have slightly different icons. Does the project use non-standard source folder layout? I.e. is the source code inside of `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` or somewhere else?

Comment: Project structure is quite different. It looks like: http://pastebin.com/NsA8Pvr1 . I have created .project file in the same folders as pom files.

Comment: You should checkout `trunk` from SVN, not `root`.